# Please help you put the table in the middle

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{2010.png} & Sauvegarder: & Ouvre une boîte de dialogue de sélection de fichier pour enregistrer les ROI actuellement définies dans un fichier de sauvegarde. \\ 
\hline 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{xroi_info.png}  & Info: & Ouvre la fenêtre Informations sur le retour sur investissement . \\ 
\hline 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{xroi_copy.png}  & Copie: & Copie le contenu de la zone d'affichage dans le presse-papiers. \\ 
\hline 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{xroi_flip.png}  & Flip: & Retourne l'image verticalement. Notez que seule l'image est retournée. les ROI définis ne sont pas déplacés. \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The third column is pretty long. Use `\usepackage{tabularx}` in the preamble and `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|X|}...\end{tabularx}` instead.

Comment: with `\centerline{...}` it will be in the middle, but it still is to wide for the page and the edges will be missing

Answer (score 2):

considering @Skillmon comment and adding some tweks for better image placing into table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[demo,               % in real document remove this option
            export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx ...
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \expandafter\patchcmd\csname Gin@ii\endcsname   % needed etoolbox
      {\setkeys {Gin}{#1}}
      {\setkeys {Gin}
          {width=12mm, height=12mm, keepaspectratio, % standard graphicx settings
           valign=t, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt,#1}       % settings from adjustbox
      }{}{}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|X|}
    \hline
\includegraphics {2010.png} & Sauvegarder: & Ouvre une boîte de dialogue de sélection de fichier pour enregistrer les ROI actuellement définies dans un fichier de sauvegarde. \\
    \hline
\includegraphics {xroi_info.png}  & Info: & Ouvre la fenêtre Informations sur le retour sur investissement . \\
    \hline
\includegraphics {xroi_copy.png}  & Copie: & Copie le contenu de la zone d'affichage dans le presse-papiers. \\
    \hline
\includegraphics {xroi_flip.png}  & Flip: & Retourne l'image verticalement. Notez que seule l'image est retournée. les ROI définis ne sont pas déplacés. \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]